# Python version change in Ansible

Tags: python, ansible, interpreter

I have got an issue when I try to change Ansible's Python interpreter from version 2 to 3 in *ansible.cfg*
When I set: `interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python3` executing playbook ends up with **No such file or directory** in ansible synchronize module.

However it works if it's set to `interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python`.
Symlinks and binaries are in right places.

Is there another way to force Ansible to use Python 3 instead of 2 ?

Ansible is 2.8.5
Python 2.7.5 but I want Ansible to use 3.6.

Comment: `interpreter_python` in ansible cfg changes the python interpreter that is used **on the host you connect to**. Is python3 installed on the target host ? If you are trying to change the version of python used on the ansible **controller** (i.e. the machine running the playbook) you need to install ansible in the correct python version (e.g. `python -m pip uninstall ansible && python3 -m pip install ansible`)