# Ansible ignoring ansible_python_interpreter as command line parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ansible, ubuntu-18.04

as you can see from the code snippet below, ansible's executable seems to be ignoring the ansible_python_interpreter variable. **Without resorting to an inventory file** (this is for a gitlab pipeline based on hashicorp's packer - which calls ansible), how could I enforce ansible to use whatever python version I have? In this case, it's an Ubuntu 18.04, so I want to switch from python-2.7 to python-3.6.

Another related cause couldto be the fact that ansibles pkg (policy?) always installs python-2.7 on bionic.

```
root@ubuntu18:~# ansible --version
ansible 2.9.27
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.17 (default, Feb 27 2021, 15:10:58) [GCC 7.5.0]
root@ubuntu18:~# /usr/bin/python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.9
root@ubuntu18:~# ansible --version -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3.6'
ansible 2.9.27
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.17 (default, Feb 27 2021, 15:10:58) [GCC 7.5.0]
root@ubuntu18:~#
```

My last resort seems to be installing ansible using pip3, but that would require a significant rewrite of both the pipeline yaml and packer's json.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: If you want to set the Python interpreter for individual hosts and groups, set the ansible_python_interpreter inventory variable.

Comment: Right, I make the same observation in my environment, RHEL 7.9, Ansible 2.9.25, Python 2.7.5 and 3.6.8, `ansible --version -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3.6'
ansible 2.9.25
...
python version = 2.7.5 ...`. `python3 --version
Python 3.6.8`.

Comment: Based on flowerysong's answer it seems to be necessary to check [Ansible: Python version won't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57167091/), [Python version change in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59767501/) or [Ansible is using wrong version of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61257164/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided any evidence that the parameter is being ignored. `ansible_python_intepreter` applies to the execution of modules on the targets, not to the execution of Ansible itself.

The Ansible control process always uses the Python interpreter it was installed under; the best way to change this is to change your install process.

Comment: Ah, "_The Ansible control process always uses the Python interpreter it was installed under;_", that explains some of the behavior I've seen. Any idea how to check under which version it was installed?

Comment: Run `ansible --version`

Comment: There I found the reason for some of the behavior: `ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible`. We may need to follow [Ansible: How to change python version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59716485/)